# Structure / blocks order on a shopping cart page

Tags: user-expectation, shopping-cart, structure

I'm working on a shopping cart page. I designed it following the idea of a progression (order > delivery > payment) so already entered informations are summarized on the left, and new informations are entered on the right part (left is past, right is next in left to right languages) *(figure A)*.

I saw on various websites the opposite structure *(figure B)* (fill new informations on the left part, summarized informations on the right).

Which structure do you think is best ?

Figure A
[image]

Figure B
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most e-commerce websites I have used over the years assume the user reads from top to bottom and left to right so the CTA would work on the right depending on the region the website is aimed at.

EDIT: Figure B would be the option to use. The user has already reviewed their items in the basket so the important area is the delivery information and this would take priority. The user would fill out this information and click Go To Payment. The order recap would serve as helpful information.

Comment: There are other factors to consider like how the layout of the page would change when viewed on other devices.

Comment: Usually supplementary information is displayed on the right side (see Related and Hot Network Questions on stackexchange). The delivery part is essential here, so on a smaller device the order recap would be positioned at the bottom or left out.

Comment: I can see that this is Step 2 of a checkout process so would agree with Nash. The Buyer may have already reviewed their order at this point so the order recap would be regarded as supplementary information.